# Trouble with C# console code. Trying to get a while loop to average 3 test scores. Final product is only using the first number entered in while loop

Tags: c#, console-application

Struggling with understanding the while loop. I'm just starting to learn programming. While testing the code, it appears as if only the second number entered gets processed into the final answer.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter test score");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        double value = Double.Parse(input);


        double sum = 0.0;
        int counter = 1;
        int total = 3;

        while (counter < total)
        {
            sum = sum + value;
            counter = counter + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter another test score");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            value = Double.Parse(input);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Test score average is: {0:N2}", sum / total);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use the *Debugger*. Put a *break-point* on the *loop* and step through, you will know why fairly quickly

Comment: @MichaelRandall i ended up moving the "sum = sum + value" before the loop  and at the end of the loop. I saw that my original code wasn't adding the initial entry into the sum.

Completely forgot about using breakpoints.(we just covered them last week)

Comment: Moving `sum = sum + value` outside the loop is not correct; try that with `int total = 0`. Your code has to work with any values, not just the one in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You need your while loop to run three times so start the counter from 0 instead of 1.

Within the loop you can ask for the test scores and add them to the `sum` and then increment the `counter`.

```cs
double sum = 0.0;
int counter = 0;
int total = 3;
while (counter < total)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter test score");
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   double value = double.Parse(input);
   sum += value;
   counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Test score average is: {0:N2}", sum / total);
Console.Read();
```

Or like this if you need the question to be different, you can ask the question outside of the loop and save the result to the `sum` variable. Since we have already asked the question once we can make the `counter` start at 1 instead of 0.

```cs
double sum = 0.0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter test score");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
double value = double.Parse(input);

sum = sum + value;

int counter = 1;
int total = 3;
while (counter < total)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another test score");
     input = Console.ReadLine();
     value = double.Parse(input);
    sum += value;
    counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Test score average is: {0:N2}", sum / total);
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score -2):

You use Wrong number

total is 3, but you need repeat 3 times calculate

counter 1 calculate clear

counter 2 calculate clear

but counter 3 is while false.

you need to fix counter <=total or counter started 0